# Column overlaps with header in article document class

Tags: two-column, article, overlap

My problem is that the right-hand column of document of class "article" overlaps with a minipage environment which serves as an header.

[image]

The document class is the following:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  twocolumn]{article}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: How the image is included into document?

Comment: Your log file should include an overfull hbox warning about this.  It looks like you are trying to insert a wider-than-one-column minipage at the top of the first column.  Unfortunately, most document classes, including `article`, prevent full-width insertions at the top of the first page.  My best guess is for you to stage an "empty" single-column `[t]` float of an appropriate length near the bottom of the input for the first column, and hope it is inserted at the desired location.  To provide better advice, a real code example is needed.